# ¿Como cargar imagen en angular 5?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, angular4

```
<div *ngFor="let datos of archivo" class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
<img class="card-img-top" src="?????" alt="Card image cap">
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-title">{{datos.titulo}}</h5>
<p class="card-text">{{datos.descripcion}}</p>

</div>
</div>
```

en mi base de datos tengo un registro con el nombre revista.png y en la carpeta /asset/img/revista.png tengo la imagen que tendria que poner dentro del bucle en src ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes solucionarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
<div *ngFor="let datos of archivo" class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" [src]="'/asset/img/' + datos.imageName" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{datos.titulo}}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{datos.descripcion}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo que haces aquí es poner la ruta base `'/asset/img/'` mas el nombre de la imagen correspondiente a ese item.

> También puedes usar String Interpolation (los `{{ }}`), pero es menos recomendado.

Comment: Gracias me recomiendas iconos para boostrap 4 que biblioteca me vendria bien

Comment: Podes usar Font Awesome, como dice el nombre es una Fuente de todos iconos. Boostrap 4 tiene sus propios iconos: Glyphicons.